C# Dev Kit - dotnet Test Explorer - No such File
I am relatively new to dotnet development. I am setting us my VSCode environment and attempting to use the C# Dev Kit to run tests within a project I am in. The project can run dotnet restore/test etc, however my VSCode does not find tests, even if I run dotnet build.
I had dotnet sdk installed but I even using the .Net Install Tool extension to install it again. My "dotnet" get placed in "/usr/local/share/dotnet" however when I look at the C3 Dev Kit - Test Explorer output I can see it's trying to pull from wrong location
0 tests discovered from  in 28.2316 ms
System.Exception: An error occurred when opening the file /usr/local/bin/dotnet with arguments "/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.302/vstest.console.dll" /parentprocessid:49332 /port:60215.
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (2): An error occurred trying to start process '/usr/local/bin/dotnet' with working directory '/Users/{USERNAME}/github/{PRIVATE-REPO}'. No such file or directory
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.ForkAndExecProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo, String resolvedFilename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean setCredentials, 

I can see it's looking in /usr/local/bin/dotnet and not /usr/local/share/dotnet. Using the extension I tried to override the property

I tried restarting and did not work. Additionally I tried creating a symlink
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/local/bin/dotnet

The extension in VSCode still fails with the same error. Any tips?
I want to be able to successfully run tests using the C# Dev Kit for Test Explorer

A previous version of the .net sdk 8.0 had placed a symlink. When i created new symlink it actually failed I wasn't paying attention. Log from C3 dev was because the old symlink was no longer valid.
